# Django REST upload multiple files with data

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create an endpoint that accepts (key/value) data and multiple files. The user can send `serial` and multiple files along with his request. Uploaded files must be saved in `FileModel` and add a relation to the `RequestModel`. The problem is when I send the request the `RequestSerializer` can't resolve the `files` and I get an error about missing the `files` field.

```
#tests.py

def test_create_request_with_files(self):

    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as file:
        file.write(b"SomeFakeData")
        file.seek(0)
        request = {
            'files': [file],
            'serial': "SomeSerial",
        }
        res = self.client.post(
            '/CreateRequest/', request, format='multipart')
        print(res.data)
        self.assertEqual(res.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

# models.py

class FileModel(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='upload_files')


class RequestModel(models.Model):
    serial = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    files = models.ManyToManyField('FileModel', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

# serializers.py

class FileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = FileModel
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('id',)


class RequestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    files = FileSerializer(many=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        files = validated_data.pop('files')
        request_model = RequestModel.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for file in files:
            file_model = FileModel.objects.create(file=file)
            request_model.files.add(file_model)
        request_model.save()
        return request_model

    class Meta:
        model = RequestModel
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('id')
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#views.py

class RequestList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = RequestModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RequestSerializer
    parser_classes = (FormParser, MultiPartParser)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = RequestSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            request_model = serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

The output of test:

```
{'files': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')]}
Fs
======================================================================
FAIL
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".tests.py", line 95, in test_create_request_with_files 
    self.assertEqual(res.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
AssertionError: 400 != 201
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem with django. You cannot pass an object when you use `multipart/form-data`. A list will be converted to `[object Object]` string.
Instead try: `file1`, `file2` etc...

I would use a dynamic parser something like:

```py
        count = 1
        files = []
        f = request.data.get('file{}'.fomat(count))
        while f is not None:
            files.append(f)
            count += 1
            f = request.data.get('file{}'.fomat(count))
```